# x11vnc server lets me connect at login screen, but after login, connection closes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc, xubuntu

I have an existing xubuntu server running on my local network. I set up x11vnc and it starts at the login screen, so I can login myself. The only problem is that every time I log in, the vnc connection closes, my vnc viewer (Remmina Remote Desktop Client) window closes, and as soon as I click connect again, I'm back at an empty login screen as if nothing happened. To get it to start before login, I've placed this command in my /etc/rc.local file before the `exit 0` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -ncache 6 -display :0 -forever -shared -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbport 5901
```

Why does it disconnect but still allow me to reconnect? Why does it disconnect in the first place? The log shows nothing wrong happening.

Answer (score 5):

Did you find the answer for this? I found Remmina would close if your colour depth was not the same on the Xserver as it is on the VNC client. vinagre didn't have an issue but I found this to be the case with Remmina.

Comment: I thought so too, but as you're familiar with how things should be done here, you'll know that requires 50 reputation.

Comment: The point of the reputation system is for you to gain the 50 points, not post comments as answers.

Comment: the point is to help people find answers, try investing your time thinking about answers instead of "points systems".

Comment: Actually you mention the reputation system. ServerFault have implemented it for a reason and you're simply trying to bypass it. That's not a huge deal I just wanted to bring it to your attention. I'll continue to give back to ServerFault through reviews and answers like I've always done.

Comment: I'm not sure of your point at all. I can't add a comment due to low reputation. Should I a) Go and try answer a dozen different questions to acquire reputation b) Throw my toys out the pram and delete my reply c) Not bother to post replies in future. Which is it?